# Jquery ajax call not working when application is hosted

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am calling a web method using jquery ajax. the call to the web method is as below

```
 function test() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "DashboardAdminService.asmx/GetSecureKey",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(response) {
                $("#KeyDetailsTable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    $(response).find("SecureKey").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).find('Status').text() == "Active")
                            $('#KeyDetailsTable > tbody').append('<tr><td>' + $(this).find('ID').text() + '</td><td>' + $(this).find('KeyName').text() + '</td><td>' + $(this).find('Description').text() + '</td><td id=' + $(this).find('ID').text() + '><a href=' + '#' + ' onclick=\'createPopup(' + $(this).find('ID').text() + ');\'>View</a><br /><a href=' + '#' + ' onclick=\'deactivateKey(' + $(this).find('ID').text() + ');\'>Deactivate</a></td></tr>')
                        else
                            $('#KeyDetailsTable > tbody').append('<tr><td>' + $(this).find('ID').text() + '</td><td>' + $(this).find('KeyName').text() + '</td><td>' + $(this).find('Description').text() + '</td><td id=' + $(this).find('ID').text() + '><a href=' + '#' + ' onclick=\'createPopup(' + $(this).find('ID').text() + ');\'>View</a><br /><a href=' + '#' + ' onclick=\'activateKey(' + $(this).find('ID').text() + ');\'>Activate</a></td></tr>')
                    });

                },
                failure: function() { alert("failed"); }
            });
        }
```

This works fine in the local machine but when hosted in server the web method call is not working and Internal Server error occurs.

Comment: are you hosting it under a virtual directory?

Comment: Javascript won't automatically adjust for the virtual directory... so it's looking under the root domain.. Eg. `www.me.com/DashboardAdminService.asmx/GetSecureKey`, where as it's hosted under `www.me.com/Virtual/DashboardAdminService.asmx/GetSecureKey`. You'll need to adjust your JS to take into account this.

Comment: i am using other jquery ajax calls and its working fine.

Comment: How's your web method declared? I'm intrigued by the fact that you declared it as returning XML instead of JSON. Have you debugged it with Firebug? what exactly does the error say in the Javascript console? Is it a 500 error (I assume it is since you say it's an "Internal Error") or a 400 error (Resource Not Found) as @Alastair suggests?

Comment: the web method returns a list. the error is 500.

Comment: ok, well then it's almost impossible for us to determine what your issue is if you have a Internal Error, but are providing us with javascript. What does your internal code look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the service URL in a different domain then Ajax method will surely fail as there is a restriction on 'cross-browser' compatibility.